# Is there any way to block the user requests to not run a job on Azure DevOps Pool agent for a specific organization group(s)?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

here is my/our company situation (very raw description):

Our company has Azure DevOps Organization_A with default permissions groups and with some specific groups created by us (e.g. [Organization_A]\Customers, [Organization_A]\Testers etc.).

We have multiple aad groups (e.g. Customer_1, Customer_2 etc.) set as members of group [Organization_A]\Customers.

All our customers run our service by using the full access PATs (every User has his own PAT).

We have multiple Agent pools with agent(s) as well (e.g. Agent_Pool_For_Customer_1, Agent_Pool_For_Customer_2 etc.).

Right now, unfortunately, every User of groups (Customer_1, Customer_2 etc.) is able to run a job on every agent within Agent_Pool_For_Customer_1, Agent_Pool_For_Customer_2 etc.

Our goal: We would like to restrict the Users within groups Customer_1, Customer_2 etc. to be not able run a job on every agent as follows:
If User_1 of group Customer_1 will send the request to run a job on agent within Agent_Pool_For_Customer_1, we will allow it.
If the same User_1 of group Customer_1 will send the request to run a job on agent within Agent_Pool_For_Customer_2, we will not allow it because it's out off his area.

As you can see, my problem is not related to Access control management of Agent pools but it's a little bit more complex/complicated.

Is there any way/mechanism we can apply to achieve our goal?

If you have further questions to understand my situation, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 sets of permissions in play here.

1. The build pool/queue permissions. With the permission on the queue you can control who can link a pipeline to a queue. So you can restrict who can grand access from a pipeline to a queue. But once assigned, anyone who has permissions on that pipeline can queue that built on that queue. Users without the Reader permission on a pool/queue can't assign a pool to a pipeline.
2. The pipeline permissions. Each pipeline is governed by a set of permissions that will allow you to configure which users can queue that specific build. By explicitly adding the user group for each pipeline
3. Pipeline folders. It's possible to create folders for pipelines in the "pipelines/all" screen. It's possible to set permissions at the folder level. By creating a folder for each customer you can configure the access to these pipelines in a single sweep. If you don't have any users working for both customers you could go as far a setting a deny rule at the folder level to explicitly deny access to pipeline folders of other clients.
4. At the project level there is a generic queue build permission. This permission controls which users can queue built at all.

Each of these levels has 3 options, allow, deny and unset. It may be required to 'unset' certain permissions at the Contributors/Customer_X groups so you can explicitly set these permissions at the pipeline and queue level.

If you want to fully separate these customers, you can create a separate team project for each customer, then only add that customers build pool to the project.

Note: there are other issues when you allow multiple 3rd parties to an Azure DevOps organisation. Users will be able to see the users, work item areas and a few other elements of other customers and you can't shield them completely. The only way to truly shield customers from each other it to create a separate Azure DevOps Organization for each customer. This adds maintenance and operational overhead, but it's the only way to truly separate the customers.

Comment: Hi Jesse,

The main problem I see now is the fact all our customers run the same pipeline so that's what makes it complicated.

Comment: There is no way to fix that with just permissions. If you grant them access tot he pipeline and the pipeline to the queue, there is no way to control the customers access to the queue.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We will implement the pipeline task / template which will control the permissions for the users using REST-API ;-)